# Deriving an expression for an n-th composition of some Mobius transformation

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $T(z)=\dfrac{1-3z}{z-3}, T^2(z)=T(T(z)),..., T^{n+1}(z)=T(T^{n}(z)),n=1,2....$ 
Could anyone advise me on how to find an expression for $T^n(z) \ ?$

I'm trying to make use of the fact that there exists constant $k$ such that $\dfrac{T(z)-1}{T(z)+1}=k\dfrac{z-1}{z+1}.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've already had the key in your hand, then it goes like

$$\dfrac{T^2(z)-1}{T^2(z) + 1} = \dfrac{T(T(z))-1}{T(T(z)) + 1} = k\dfrac{T(z)-1}{T(z)+1} = k^2 \dfrac{z-1}{z+1}$$

Similarly by induction you get

$$\dfrac{T^n(z)-1}{T^n(z) + 1} = k^n \dfrac{z-1}{z+1}$$